# Ant cannot find wildcard directory in <exec> task

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

I'm using Jenkins/ant in order to deploy my applications to remote servers.

I was having issues with the ant `<scp>` task for trying to scp a set of directories specified by a wildcard (e.g. scp -r my/path/and/directory_* user@remote:/remote/path/to/directory), so I've been trying to just run it using the `<exec>` task instead.

See code below:

```
<property name="built_directories" value="${workspace}/build_\*" />

<exec dir="${workspace}" executable="scp" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="-r -i ${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa ${built_directories} deployer@@@{SERVER}:${remote_build_dir}"></arg>
</exec>
```

Jenkins/ant gives me the error:

[exec] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/app-head-stage-deployment/workspace/build_*: No such file or directory

I've also tried the following, but receive the same error:

```
<exec dir="${workspace}" executable="scp" failonerror="true">
     <arg value="-r"></arg>
     <arg value="-i"></arg>
     <arg value="${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa"></arg>
     <arg value="${built_directories}"></arg>
     <arg value="deployer@@@{SERVER}:${remote_build_dir}"></arg>
</exec>
```

I've been trying to figure out if somehow I need to escape the asterisk in order for it to be parsed correctly by the shell, but haven't found much information.

EDITS:

Trying out @whiskeyspider's config, see below:

```
<exec dir="${workspace}" executable="sh" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="scp" />
    <arg value="-r" />
    <arg value="-i" />
    <arg value="${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa" />
    <arg value="${built_directories} deployer@@@{SERVER}:${remote_build_dir}" />
</exec>
```

I've tried splitting the last arg into separate `<arg>` elements as well, but now I get the following error:

[exec] usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
[exec]            [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
[exec]            [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

And I'm guessing that means that it doesn't recognize the arguments properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to launch a shell, in order for the wildcard to expand.  For example:

```
<exec executable="sh">
    <arg value="-c"/> 
    <arg value="scp"/>
    ...
</exec>
```

Comment: Is there some way to see exactly what the <exec> command is running at runtime? I thought I had it setup properly (about to edit the main post, so hold on for that), but I'm getting a new error now.

Comment: @robert.bo.roth Try separating your last argument into two separate lines (it's actually two arguments).  Alternatively, after the "-c", you can try `<arg line=""/>` adding all your args there in one line.

Comment: I got it to work by doing 2 args. First one is just "-c", and the second one contains the entire scp command. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to quote the string (though I probably could have figured out the specific character(s) that needed escaping:

```
<exec executable="sh" osfamily="unix">
    <arg value="-c"/> 
    <arg line="'chmod uga+x ${project.build.directory}/dist/bin/*.sh'"/>
</exec>
```